# Incorrect tree view of document structure with Winedt, VerbatimPlus and listings package

Tags: listings, verbatim, winedt

I´m having some trouble working with Winedt 8 and 9 and [VerbatimPlus](http://www.winedt.org/Config/menus/VerbatimPlus.php) add-on. Here is my MWE.

File "main.tex"

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Codificação da entrada
\usepackage{lmodern}        % Fonte Latin Modern
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % Codificação da Saída
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}  % Português Brasil
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\section{Teste}
% including file with document divisions
\lstinputlisting{listingerror.tex}

\begin{lstlisting}
  \section{Not to show in Tree view}
  \begin{tabular}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

File "listingerror.tex"

```
\chapter{chap1}
\section{sec1}
\subsection{subsec}
\subsubsection{subsec}
\paragraph{par}
```

To understand the problem just look at the images below. The first shows the Winedt 9 tree view of the document structure without the `VerbatimPlus` installed. It´s the known problem of Winedt not working right with verbatim-like environments like `lstlisting`

[image: Winedt 9 without VerbatimPlus installed]

The second image shows the same file but now with the `VerbatimPlus` installed. The problem is that the syntax highlight is correct, but the tree view is not. It´s gathering the content of the `lstinputlisting` as real divisions of the document not considering it´s a verbatim environment.

[image]

I hope I made myself clear about the problem. What I want is have the correct tree view and corret highlight of the document in winedt. Anybody knows how to fix it?

Comment: Thanks @T.Verron  I read a lot here but it´s my first question. Hope everything is ok with the rules of the tex.sx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update (2017-02-14)

The workaround desribed in this answer is not needed anymore if you upgrade to WinEdt 10.2.

WinEdt 10.2 considers verbatim input like the one inserted with `\lstinputlisting` like *"verbatim"* stuff, that is nothing inside them is collected in its Tree and Gather interfaces and it is not used for folding purposes.

---

### Original answer

There's no easy solution for this.

The only way not to collect sectional commands is to not collect the file.

To do that, Go to "Options" -> "Options Interface" and double-click the "Input Directives" branch:

[image]

A local copy of `Input.ini` gets opened. In this file remove the lines

```
  DIRECTIVE="\lstinputlisting[????]{?}"
    EXTENSION="*;.tex"
    PATH="%P;%p;%@('TEXINPUTS');"
  DIRECTIVE="\lstinputlisting{?}"
    EXTENSION="*;.tex"
    PATH="%P;%p;%@('TEXINPUTS');"
```

At this point press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd> to reload the file.

Now the unwanted sectional commands coming from `listingerror.tex` are not collected anymore:

[image]

Comment: thanks. It worked. I don´t see the point to winedt gather the contents of a verbatim-like environment. If VerbatimPlus made this modification to the `input.ini` the macro for installations should be updated. Or maybe there is a point I´m missing. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: @karlkoeller, is it possible to add new verbatim environment to VerbatimPlus?

Comment: @fajar I've [answered your question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214691/27635)