# Getting WinEdt to ignore lstlisting

Tags: listings, verbatim, winedt

**WinEdt 9.0** gives me incorrect TOC in its side panel when I use `listings` package to illustrate a piece of LaTeX code:

[image: WinEdt TOC Error]

[image]

How can I get WinEdt to ignore `\begin{lstlisting}` ...`\end{lstlisting}` (and every other verbatim environments) in its structure collection process?

The closest question I can find in this site is this: [Incorrect tree view of document structure with Winedt, VerbatimPlus and listings package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212179/incorrect-tree-view-of-document-structure-with-winedt-verbatimplus-and-listings)
But I could not resolve my problem using the solution there.

Anybody?

Comment: What happens if you try the solution given in that other question? Are you using VerbatimPlus as well?

Comment: @T.Verron. It solves different problem I think. Moreover, somehow I could not find the problematic string in my WinEdt's Input.ini file (my guess it's inserted by VerbatimPlus, I'm not sure). And no, I'm not using VerbatimPlus. Just `listings`, as shown above.

Comment: The question is indeed about another problem, my bad. However, from what I understand, the OP was using Verbatimplus precisely to achieve what you want (note how the "Not to be shown in tree view" section disappeared between his two screenshots.

Comment: @T.Verron. Ah, yes, I did not know that VerbatimPlus is a plugin for WinEdt. My bad. I installed it and, voila, problem solved! If you could just make it an answer, I'll gladly accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @fajar. I made the question you mentioned. You will only have to edit the lines in edit.ini if you use `lstinputlisting` to include latex code with sectioning commands. Besides that all work fine, as far as I know.

Comment: Hi @Smarzaro. Thank you for the information. Now, is it possible to add new verbatim environment with VerbatimPlus? For example, using the command `\lstnewenvironment`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part of the the answer is clear from the comments above.

WinEdt only recognises `verbatim` as a "verbatim" environment. If you want more control on these kind of environments you have to install the plugin of mine [VerbatimPlus](http://www.winedt.org/config/modes/VerbatimPlus.html). With this, you have support for environments coming from the following packages: `listings`, `moreverb`, `verbatim` and `fancyvrb`.

Now, if you want to add your personal environments to the list of supported ones, follow these steps. Let's suppose that you have created a new environment `cplusplus` through the `\lstnewenvironment` command.

Go to "Options" -> "Options Interface" and double-click the "Switches" item:

[image]

A local copy of `Switches.ini` gets opened. In this file, let's say after the lines

```
SWITCH="\begin{verbatim*} .. \end{verbatim*}"
  ENABLED=1
  MODE_FILTER="TeX|INS;STY;AUX"
  START="\"
  STOP="\"
  HIGHLIGHT_START=0
  STEP_OVER_STOP=1
  HIGHLIGHT_STOP=0
  SCOPE=4
  DOMINANT_PRIORITY=0
  STRICT_PRIORITY=1
  PRIORITY=9
  INDENTED=0
  BOLN_ONLY=0
  CASE_SENSITIVE=1
  VERBATIM=1
  START1_TRIGGER=""
  START2_TRIGGER="begin{verbatim*}"
  STOP1_TRIGGER=""
  STOP2_TRIGGER="end{verbatim*}"
    TEXT_COLOR="xclVerbatim"
    DEFAULT_FONT=1
  CUSTOM_BACKGROUND=1
  GRADIENT_BACKGROUND=256
  TRANSPARENT=128
  GRADIENT_COLOR="xclEnvBkLeftGradient"
  BACKGROUND_COLOR="xclEnvBk"
  RELATIVE_RIGHT_MARGIN=1
  RIGHT_MARGIN=0
  INDENTED_LEFT_MARGIN=0
  LEFT_MARGIN=0
```

add the following lines

```
SWITCH="\begin{cplusplus} .. \end{cplusplus}"
  ENABLED=1
  MODE_FILTER="TeX|INS;STY;AUX"
  START="\"
  STOP="\"
  HIGHLIGHT_START=0
  STEP_OVER_STOP=1
  HIGHLIGHT_STOP=0
  SCOPE=4
  DOMINANT_PRIORITY=0
  STRICT_PRIORITY=1
  PRIORITY=9
  INDENTED=0
  BOLN_ONLY=0
  CASE_SENSITIVE=1
  VERBATIM=1
  START1_TRIGGER=""
  START2_TRIGGER="begin{cplusplus}"
  STOP1_TRIGGER=""
  STOP2_TRIGGER="end{cplusplus}"
    TEXT_COLOR="xclVerbatim"
    DEFAULT_FONT=1
  CUSTOM_BACKGROUND=1
  GRADIENT_BACKGROUND=256
  TRANSPARENT=128
  GRADIENT_COLOR="xclEnvBkLeftGradient"
  BACKGROUND_COLOR="xclEnvBk"
  RELATIVE_RIGHT_MARGIN=1
  RIGHT_MARGIN=0
  INDENTED_LEFT_MARGIN=0
  LEFT_MARGIN=0
```

As you can see, the word "cplusplus" appears 4 times in the above code. Replace them with your custom environment name. Repeat it for all your custom environments.

At this point press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd> to reload the file.

That's all. Now your custom environments are not taken into consideration when building the document's tree.